# ASP.NET Gridview with Select and its ID being visible or hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using a GridView, I have it so that when the "select" link for the row is clicked, the item (in this case "category") is put into a text box to be renamed or edited in some way.

However, in order to save it, I need the ID of the selected row. I can get the ID if I show it as a column and do this in the CategoryGridView_SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
GridViewRow row = CategoryGridView.SelectedRow;

Session["SelectedID"] = row.Cells[2].Text;
```

However, I don't like that I have to display the ID column because of aesthetic reasons and also I just don't like people seeing my IDs.

On the other hand, if I hide the ID column in the GridView, how can I associate the Category text back to the original row in the Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this purpose you can use DataKeyNames and DataKeys properties of grid view

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataKeys property to associate the id's with a particular row and then retain the value in postback or else where.

Check this link:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/GridView-Hidden-Column.aspx) is a short tutorial that deals with exaclty the same issue that you have.

Although the code is in VB, I think that you'll get the idea, the solution is pretty straightforward.

Good luck!